# Automate file upload in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I have written a node.js server to accept file.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {

    var newPath = __dirname + "/"+req.files.displayImage.name;
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.redirect("back");
    });
  });
});
```

This works perfect with HTML form which is

```
<form action="http://localhost/", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file", name="displayImage">
  <input type="submit", name="Upload">
```

But I want to remove HTML UI and want to have node.js code to automatically consume file. I am OK to have file as hard-coded path.

I need a node.js script which can call server code and send a file to upload.

Any help?

Comment: So you want to read an ordinary file on the server's disk? That has nothing to do with HTTP or web servers.

Comment: Basically client will upload a file. I am expecting it to be .zip. This is just a basic code I have got. I want this upload process to be automated by client. So want to remove HTML UI.

Comment: So how will the client upload the file?? :o

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My server code is going to accept a .zip file. Client will have that particular file. Current HTML UI needs user to select a file and click submit button. I want to have a client node.js code, which will pick up file and submit it to server. Am I clear?

Comment: @Gaurav I think you're going to have a security issue here. If the client does not "pick" the file, how do you know that you have access to that file? This sounds like a giant security hole, which probably means that it does not exist.

Comment: You can achieve the functionality using Java Applet embedded into your node.js view. But Applet must be properly signed and trusted by client (Privileged applets).